# start PreferenceActivity from onClick method in Android

Tags: android, menu, onclick, preferences

I've used the following tutorial to create my preferences page :
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html
But i want the configurations to be displayed in another activity (works fine) and i want to call this page from one of my methods (not from onOptionsItemSelected)
When i try using `startActivity(new Intent(this, QuickPrefsActivity.class));` i get an error :

```
The constructor Intent(new View.OnLongClickListener(){}, Class<QuickPrefsActivity>) is undefined
```

I guess it happens since it's not a base activity, so how can i open this preferences page otherwise ? (not by menu click)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can not use `this` inside on button click, instead use `ClassName.this`

for example

```
Intent i = new Intent(ClassName.this, SecondClass.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: no problem, :) if my answer helped you can mark it as answered so it doesnt go to unasnwered section. (click on transparent thick)